# How to fill cell value from another table?

Tags: mysql

I have two tables. A and B

```
SELECT projectid, statusid from A;
```

Results as below:

[image]

```
SELECT statusid, status from B
```

Results as below:

[image]

Now how can I have the result as below to replace all stutusid with the value from table B.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could use `JOIN`:

```
SELECT A.projectid, B.status from A JOIN b ON A.statusid = b.statusid;
```

---

EDIT:

> *I want to have all those status codes replaced by "its meaning" which is from another table B. So "join" wont do this job but only showing me matched results from both A and B table*

I don't understand the requirements. This is exactly what join is doing, showing corresponding value from second table. If for example you don't have the specific code you should use `LEFT OUTER JOIN`

```
SELECT A.projectid, COALESCE(B.status, 'Unknown') AS status
from A 
LEFT JOIN b ON A.statusid = b.statusid;
```

Maybe you are searching for correlated subquery(but it will be literally the same as `JOIN`) if there is no duplicates on table B

```
SELECT A.projectid,
       (SELECT B.status FROM B WHERE A.statusid = b.statusid) AS status
FROM A 

-- if it returns error query returned more than one row then b.statusid is not unique
    SELECT A.projectid,
       (SELECT B.status FROM B WHERE A.statusid = b.statusid ORDER BY ... LIMIT 1) AS status
FROM A
```

Comment: I tried this already, this is not what I am looking for, from query A, I will have a list of over 3K entries, each entry will have a status code, I dont want to see that status code (number), instead, I want to have all those status codes replaced by "its meaning" which is from another table B. So "join" wont do this job but only showing me matched results from both A and B table

Comment: The query provided should give you exactly what you have asked. If you need something different, you should better explain your requirements.

Comment: @RootLoop Please post https://dbfiddle.uk demo and desired resultset. Your question is vague